# What happens to other threads when main thread calls sys.exit()?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, daemon, exit

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread

> When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other
>   threads survive. On SGI IRIX using the native thread implementation,
>   they survive. On most other systems, **they are killed without executing
>   try ... finally clauses** or executing object destructors.

And here, in the docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading) it says:

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread.

Let's talk only about non-daemon threads here. Since, the first quote does not make any special reference to non-daemon threads, I would assume that even non-daemon threads should be killed if the main thread is exiting. However, the second quote suggests otherwise. And in fact, the non-daemon threads are indeed not killed when the main thread exits. So, what's the point of first quote here?

Comment: Write code and try it out

Comment: It would seem that the `thread` module handles everything as daemon threads, while `threading` adds the concept of "non daemon" threads.

Comment: @user2799617: I did write code and came to the conclusion "the non-daemon threads are indeed not killed when the main thread exits". That's why, I am wondering when does the first quote apply since my system is probably one of those "most other systems": Ubuntu 12.10 running python 2.7

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Thanks, that does make sense. I suspected that, but just needed a confirmation

Comment: @gjain If you read the last part of the threading page, there's some interesting info equalling daemon threads with thread module created threads; _"This can be most easily achieved by only performing imports from non-daemon threads created through the threading module. **Daemon threads and threads created directly with the thread module** will require some other form of synchronization to ensure they do not attempt imports after system shutdown has commenced."_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation you reference comes from two **different** modules:  `thread` and `threading`.  `thread` is a low-level module providing more-or-less direct access to the platform's idea of what "thread" means.  `threading` supplies a higher-level notion of "thread" with less platform dependence.

That's why the docs say different things.  What happens to a low-level `thread` "thread" at exit does depend on what the platform C's version of threads do, but in any case Python makes no attempt to - or not to - shut them down cleanly.

A `threading.Thread` is different.  Part of Python's normal shutdown processing is to `.join()` all non-daemon `threading.Thread` threads.  So the program won't end at all until all non-daemon `threading.Thread` threads have ended (which is the programmer's responsibility to ensure).  Note that the low-level `thread` module threads have no concept of `.join()` - `.join()` is a higher-level concept implemented **by** the distinct `threading` module.

Advice:  use `threading` instead of `thread` unless you have excellent reasons to use `thread` instead.  `threading` is better behaved and supplies many useful tools.  An example of when using `thread` is better?  I can't think of one ;-)

Note:  in Python 3, the low-level `thread` module is renamed to `_thread`.  As usual, the leading underscore hints "better not to mess with this - but it's here if you must".